# Post apocalyptic story about a city with an underground metro

Tags: story-identification

I read a story in the early 2000's (don't know how contemporary was the book). I *think* it was a Russian author but I'm not sure, but I read it in Russian. The story had a man live in a post apocalyptic city presumably in the far future. I remember that their lives were quite comfortable and automated. He didn't know about anything outside the confines of the city but he started to question everything and eventually found an underground train / metro station that connected that city to other cities worldwide in the past.

I don't remember much else from the story, but I do remember that knowledge about the world was highly restricted, and the whole train / metro connecting to the outer world was very memorable as an image.

Comment: My first thought was Metro 2033, but I haven't read it and don't know if it matches beyond the basic premise.

Comment: @Raj thanks for the comment! It doesn't seem to be Metro 2033 from reading the synopsis and the plot points on Wikipedia. In the story I'm looking for the trains / metro were a lesser point I guess, and the city was dystopian / utopian - I don't remember any invasion / bloody conflict, at least at the point I read it. And it took quite a while for the person to steer from their "normal" path and start finding all those ancient technologies and knowledges. I don't know much beyond that :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds like [Against the Fall of Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_the_Fall_of_Night), a 1953 novel by Arthur C. Clarke that was originally published in English.

In the novel, the main character Alvin lives in a mostly automated, post-scarcity city (Diaspar) in the middle of hundreds of miles of desert wasteland in Earth's far future. He wants to leave the city and discover what else is out there, and eventually finds a still-working ancient subway that takes him to the city of Lys, which has a different culture and attitude toward the outside. It is strongly implied that Diaspar and Lys are the only remaining cities on Earth, and that the rest of humanity left Earth eons ago in search of ascension to higher states of being.

I suspect this may be it because the discovery of the subway is a major event in the book and the protagonist is uncomfortable living in his city and wants to explore.

Comment: Re-written and published as *The City and the Stars* in 1956 according to wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_and_the_Stars

Comment: YES! This is it! Thank you SO MUCH! I will be reading this again now that you helped me find it.

Comment: I have read both versions. Clarke made a number of changes in the story, but the points sought by the asker are certainly present in both.

Answer (score 2):

The description reminded me of Sever Gansovsky's Part of the World (Chast' etogo mira). Alas, that takes place in a near future, and the hero after some (mis)adventures gets lost in the bowels of a completely automated but deserted city. Still, the image was certainly memorable:

> A breeze now touched his face. Something glimmered in the darkness ahead.
>
> A half-turn. A half-open grate.
>
> Kisch pushed it open and looked out. Then he climbed out into some kind of recess and stood up.
>
> To the right and left stretched a brightly lit wide tunnel with greenish walls. And a yard-wide rail ran down the center.
>
> A magnetic road. And he was in one of the repair recesses.
>
> On the right he heard a quickly increasing whistle. Something flashed in front of his eyes, and the wind tugged at him so hard he had to grab the grating. Vague spots danced around, the wind roared. Then it was all over. Silence.
>
> “So. That’s just fine. The cars have passed. ...”
>
> He carefully inspected the surroundings, with a determined efficiency that was a surprise to him. His strength seemed to have returned — even in areas he never before knew. From here he would be able to find his way out, even if it took days. The road must have recesses at regular intervals, so all he had to do was determine how far apart they were. And not be caught by a train as it whizzed by at 150 miles an hour.
>
> Kisch started to tick off the seconds in his mind. He had counted to fifty three times when he heard a whistle and stepped back in his recess.
>
> It all happened just as it had before. And then once more — the trains flew by every three and one-half minutes.
>
> He waited out just one more train, noticing that the cars came right up to the tunnel wall. He jumped out and sprinted along the central rail. Ten seconds, twenty, ... He felt winded. Then he realized that he had gone past the limit of a minute and a half. The greenish polished walls shone evenly. Kisch picked up the pace. On his right he saw a dark shadow in the wall. He ran to it, squeezed into the recess, and at that very moment a sharp whistle blasted and the wind tugged at him with a soft but unrelenting force. The cars were flying by in their automated course.
>
> When everything had settled down he shook his head, puffing madly.
>
> “That was too close a shave.”
>
> He realized that he could get rid of his shoes and ran the next stretch barefoot. It was better — he finished with thirty seconds to spare. He took off his jacket, putting his identifier in his pants pocket. Running was even easier, and things started looking brighter. Another two intervals and he had the knack of it, taking only one train to catch his breath. He even began wondering how many passengers there were in each train, whether they could see him, and if so, what they thought of him.
>
> In the seventh interval he felt a little tired but caught himself in time to run for all he was worth. He made it to the recess just as the whistle sounded.